# Check if two adjacent string tokens are equal

Tags: java, arraylist, stack, stringtokenizer

I've got code pasted below that is a very basic reverse polish notation calculator. It can take an input from a text file, tokenize it and add the elements into an ArrayList, complete the computation, and feed back the answer. I've managed to handle too few operators by making sure it ends with a operator. Now I need to find out how to handle too many operators, and basically the only way an equation has too many operations is if two of them are adjacent to each other. My question, then, is how do I check if there are two `/ * + -` next to each other?

```
package project5;
// Import
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Project5 extends IOException {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        // Open and read input file
        String fileName = "input.txt";

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

        while(line != null)
        {
            System.out.println(compute(line)); // Compute and display answer

            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }        
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    public static String compute(String input) {
        // Make new arraylist
        List<String> processedList = new ArrayList<>();
        // make sure there's content in the input file
        if (!input.isEmpty()) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                processedList.add(st.nextToken());
            }
        } else {
            return "Error, no input!"; // else return "Error, no input"
        }
        // Make a new stack
        Stack<String> tempList = new Stack<>();
        // Make a new iterator
        Iterator<String> iter = processedList.iterator();
        // Make sure there are enough operators
        if(processedList.get(processedList.size()-1).equals("+") ||
            processedList.get(processedList.size()-1).equals("-") ||
            processedList.get(processedList.size()-1).equals("/") ||
            processedList.get(processedList.size()-1).equals("*")) {
            // Continue while there's more calculations
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                String temp = iter.next();
                // Check if content is correctly formatted
                if (temp.matches("[0-9]*")) {
                    tempList.push(temp);
                } else if (temp.matches("[*-/+]")) {
                    // perform appropriate operations
                    if (temp.equals("*")) {
                        int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int result = ls * rs;
                        tempList.push("" + result);
                    } else if (temp.equals("-")) {
                        int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int result = ls - rs;
                        tempList.push("" + result);
                    } else if (temp.equals("/")) {
                        int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int result = ls / rs;
                        tempList.push("" + result);
                    } else if (temp.equals("+")) {
                        int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int result = ls + rs;
                        tempList.push("" + result);
                    }
                } else {
                    return "Error"; // return "error" if inappropriately formatted
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Check your formatting\n");
        }
        return tempList.pop(); // pop the item off the stack
    }
}
```

Comment: a brute force solution for this is by listing all the possible combination from `/ * + -` and use `.contains()` to check

Comment: Actually, I just realized that having two operators side by side already throws an "Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException". How do I handle that to where it'll display "Check your formatting" rather than the error message?

Comment: add `try{}` and `catch(){}` block where your `catch` looks something like this: `catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Check your formatting");}`

Comment: I came to the same solution, and that works. Thanks! c: